# current class removed when refreshing page

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have created a dynamic link list in one page...

When a click is done on one link on that dynamic list i want to show to user that link is active, so i will add one class to the clicked link but that new class removed suddenly when page refreshing.

I want to keep that class till user click another one link. How can i achieve?

My code is given below :

```
<style>
.activearea {
     background: #3f7aa5 !important;
}
</style>

<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('a.areamenu').click(function(){
        $('a.areamenu').removeClass("activearea");
        $(this).addClass("activearea");
     });
});
</script>
```

This is my dynamic link

```
<li>
    <a class="areamenu" href="/areas/'.$categorynameNavLink.'/'.$subcatnameNAV.'/'.$subcatid.'/">'.$subcatname.'</a>
</li>
```

Comment: you need to store the information somewhere... like in a cookie or in local storage

Comment: `but that new class removed suddenly when page refreshing`. Suddenly! Of course, you are refreshing the page. Make AJAX request instead.

Comment: Or you must work with ajax call and prevent link to go to another page. It's more an erchitecture problem than a code problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to use [localstorage()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/API/DOM/Storage) like,

```
$(function(){
    // if localstorage activeArea is set then add activearea class to menu
    if(localStorage && localStorage.getItem('activeArea')==1){
       $('a.areamenu').addClass("activearea");
    } 
    $('a.areamenu').click(function(){
       $('a.areamenu').removeClass("activearea");
       $(this).addClass("activearea");
       localStorage.setItem('activeArea',1);// set value in localstorage
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Changing the class via AJAX only stores the information locally. So, whenever you refresh the page, this data is lost.

To get around this, you could get your page to remember this by setting a cookie.

Comment: Why is the information lost?

Answer (score 1):

try it with PHP script like below,

Assuming page URl will be like: http://example.com/areas/categorynameNavLink/subcatnameNAV/123

```
<?php
$CatSelectID =  end(explode('/',curPageURL()));
?>

<li>
<a <?php if($subcatid == $CatSelectID) echo 'class="areamenu"';?> href="/areas/'.$categorynameNavLink.'/'.$subcatnameNAV.'/'.$subcatid.'/">'.$subcatname.'
</a>
</li>

<?php
function curPageURL() {
 $pageURL = 'http';
 if ($_SERVER["HTTPS"] == "on") {$pageURL .= "s";}
 $pageURL .= "://";
 if ($_SERVER["SERVER_PORT"] != "80") {
  $pageURL .= $_SERVER["SERVER_NAME"].":".$_SERVER["SERVER_PORT"].$_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"];
 } else {
  $pageURL .= $_SERVER["SERVER_NAME"].$_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"];
 }
 return $pageURL;
}
?>
```

Note: not tested

Answer (score 0):

In click function use e.preventDefault()